# How remove class only when scroll up?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove existing class **only when scroll is up**.

I  have tried is as below:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
   var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (scroll >= 100) {
         // removeClass
      }
})
```

...but only works when scroll is down.

Any suggestion in this regard?
Thanks

Comment: What is exactly your problem?

Comment: Create a variable `previousTop` and check current value. if it is less, scroll is up

Comment: May be this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814086/how-can-i-know-whether-the-scroll-of-the-user-is-up-or-down

Comment: You have here the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326845/how-can-i-determine-the-direction-of-a-jquery-scroll-event

Comment: @Balder This it's works, but it is too sensitive when changing the scroll direction. Any way to regulate sensitivity?